# У подгружаемых js-файлов в админке не видна JQuery

Tags: django

Почему-то у моих подгружаемых js-файлов в админке не видна jquery.
На выходе в хтмл смотрю следующее. Мои файлы equipment.js и thumb.js. Моя медийная папка site-media.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/equipment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/js/thumb.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/inlines.min.js"></script>
```

Сами шаблоны админки не трогал, то есть только через class Media в admin.py менял.
Так же непонятно, что за `static`. 
Использую [django-admin-tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
Вот мои настройки

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'site_media')

MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

Вот URL адреса:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
   (r'^attachments/', include('attachments.urls')),                     
   url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
   (r'^upload_images/', include('upload_images.urls')),
   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls) ),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'site_media'}),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

А вы в admin.py для своей модели что написали в Media?

У меня обычно так:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    class Media:
        js = ('/static/js/jquery.min.js', '/static/js/your_custom.js')
```

Где /static/js/jquery.min.js - мой jquery, который я туда положил. Звучит странно, но вот так, глубже не разбирался, чего мелочами голову забивать. На выходе когда смотришь исходник в браузере, загружается два jquery ... Ну или доку смотрите:
[тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)